# angular 2 post call to return mailbox mail

Tags: javascript, angular, http-post

i am creating a POST request to retrieve back a list of emails in a mailbox to display. I am a little lost on how to properly format my POST request since i am not really submitting any data - for a return i am expecting a json file in which i pull out information from to the view page.

This is what i have in my serviceFile.ts:

```
getInbox(): Observable<any>{
        let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // 
        let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 

        return this._http.post(this.inboxUrl+new Date().getTime(), '', options)
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

In my component.ts:

```
 getInbox(){
   this.serviceFile.getInbox().subscribe(
       data => {this.inbox = data;}
   )
 }
```

ERROR Handler:

```
  private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
```

when i run this i get multiple errors:

```
serviceFile.ts:20 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (http.umd.js:777)....  

core.umd.js:3064 EXCEPTION: error.json is not a function (repeated two more times)
```

Any advice or guidance... I am thrown off a bit by the fact that even though i really don't have a 'body' to submit yet i still have to make a POST request.

Comment: Could you show `this.handleError` method? I think, you have an error there.

Comment: @DenisReshetniak I went ahead and updated my post with the `handleError` method.

Comment: what is status of your request. check in the dev tool. I think your post request returning html instead of xml

Comment: Your error is server side, not client side. You are getting 'Unexpected token <' because you are expecting a JSON file but receiving something starting with '<', most likely a 404 not found which is the usual html response that starts with '<html>'. The second error is because a Response.error doesn't have a json() function.